# EnableHighDpiScaling causes images in rich text to be stretched 2x

Tags: qt, qml, qt-quick

I'm displaying simple rich text with images in a `TextEdit` item:

```
TextEdit {
    textFormat: TextEdit.RichText
    text: "<h1>Image test</h1><br/><img src='test.png'/>"
    readOnly: true
}
```

If I disable `Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling` then image size looks fine (screenshot on the top).

However if I enable `Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling` (and I'm on a HiDPI screen so it should be enabled), the image appears as twice the size it should be* (screenshot on the bottom).

I tried also to enable attribute `Qt::AA_UseHighDpiPixmaps`, but the "@2x" version of the image it seems it is never picked up and the attribute has no effect whatsoever

Is there any way to control the image size in relation to screen's DPI?

* the image itself (test.png) is a screenshot taken on the same machine with Windows' Snip Tool; that's where the reference size comes from.

[image]

Comment: What happens when you display the `test.png` in both normal DPI and high DPI mode when using the Image component instead of using Text with RichEdit?

Comment: Without `Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling`, the image size in `Image` and `TextEdit` is the same. With `Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling` the `Image` item would load the "@2x" image (which displays in the correct size). If I do not provide a "@2x" image, then `Image` and `TextEdit` would show the same image in same size (double size).

Answer (score 0):

Most probably, the `TextEdit` component just doesn't care about HiDPI in case of images.

However, you should be able to take care of that yourself by implementing your own [`QQuickImageProvider`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qquickimageprovider.html) which would `QCoreApplication::testAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling)` internally and return an image/pixmap of corresponding size depending on that.

Haven't tried it though.

**Update:**

Note that, generally speaking, it's not enough to just multiply or divide the size by 2. You should use a scale factor of the screen which can be, for instance, 1.25.